# should I flag a question on R to " it is very low quality" when lacking a sample data set?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

For questions on programming language that manipulate data sets, it is usually very useful that the person who asks the question provides a reproducible example (=a sample data set, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)).

1. How should we ask gently for a sample data set? Should we flag the question to " it is very low quality"? It is a bit painful to add a comment each time and to argue until the person realizes that he/she will get unprecise answer until a sample data set is provided.
2. Could we imagine a way to avoid as much as possible to have people asking vague questions that clearly require a sample data set to get a precise answer? Either though incentives, flags, or by improving the website (for instance providing in the question form a specific location for passing a sample data set, or the person who asks the question should be asked whether or not it is relevant to add a sample data set?)

Comment: You should flag the question to be closed only if it really cannot be answered unless a data set is provided. The "very low quality" flag is only reserved for incoherent garbage - the fact that you can even tell it is an R question means you should not be flagging it as VLQ. Questions that cannot be answered because they lack critical information should be closed instead as it gives askers a chance to edit them and get them reopened.

Comment: May I know the reason why it's tagged as [tag:feature-request]? Is it because of the second point? As of current, I see that as very vague feature-request. I think you might want to retag this as [tag:discussion] first, and if the request becomes more concrete, then readd the tag.

Comment: @AndrewT. yes, for the second point. Thank you for the feedback, I edited the tags as suggested

Answer (score 1):

No. As I understand it flags should only be used for things that *really* need a moderators attention. Comments and/or down-votes and/or close-votes should be used for poorly written questions. Flags are sent to the relatively small number of moderators. Comments and down-votes are read (hopefully) by the asker and they can act upon them to improve their question. Close-votes are where the general Stackoverflow community makes a decision.

Perhaps posting a link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would be appropriate for the case in you question.